# How to stop having anonymous user in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, middleware

So I have a django project and there is one view(home view) which displays the posts of the followed users and that requires a user to be authenticated, if there is no user loged in, then the code returns a 'AnonimousUser' is not iterable error and I will like my code to redirect the anonymous user to the login page if the person is on the home view. After some investigation I realized that this can be done with a custom middleware but I dont know how to do it so currently that middleware just prints if a user is logged in or if it is anonymous. What can I do to Complete this middleware and get rid of that Anoniomus User error?

middleware.py

```
class LoginRequiredMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        if(request.user.is_authenticated):
            print(Authenticated")
        else:
            print("Anonimous user")
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    user = Following.objects.get(user=request.user)
    followed_users = [i for i in user.followed.all()]
    followed_users.append(request.user)

    contents = Post.objects.filter(user__in = followed_users)

    context = {
        "contents": contents,
    }
    print("nice")
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('login', views.login, name='login'),
    path('register', views.register, name='register'),
    path('logout', views.logout, name='logout'),
    path('<username>/', views.profile, name='profile'),
]
```

If you have any questions or need to see more code please let me know;)

Comment: how about this [django-login-required-middleware](https://pypi.org/project/django-login-required-middleware/) package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no required to writing a custom middleware.

You can restrict the anonymous user in your view like this

```
def home(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect  ('your_login_url')
    user = Following.objects.get(user=request.user)
    followed_users = [i for i in user.followed.all()]
    followed_users.append(request.user)
```

OR you can user `login_required` decorator

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url='your_login_url')
def home(request):
    user = Following.objects.get(user=request.user)
    followed_users = [i for i in user.followed.all()]
    followed_users.append(request.user)
```

Comment: Yeah it is the best choice, as you can control which views needs authentication which not

Comment: Hey I have a question, How can I redirect if the login view is in other app? would it be `return redirect(my_app/login)`?

Comment: `return redirect('app_name:login_url_namr')`

Comment: @JuanMartinZabala  See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) for more info

Comment: Ok thank you! I will try that in 1 hour, I am not in my home now. I will let you know what happens;)

Comment: Hey!! It worked! btw by some reason using the appname was not necesarry.

Comment: @JuanMartinZabala if app_name was provided then it's mandatory.If you are working with multiple apps then it's a better practice to configure a app_name in your urls

Answer (score 0):

Well, the above answer contains the two solutions to your problem, **you could also use django.contrib.auth.mixins, they are used for Class-based view**. The links for documentation are

1.https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/mixins/
2.https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible issue might be that you have set the action of login template form to redirect to some page e.g.

So, it never validates the login VIEW to proceed the authentication. If so, try to set action="" of login form and write the login view which renders the login.html template.